# How do I make this regex expression work for multiple scenarios?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the word RESULT from both of the following examples using Regex.

1. https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT%3Futm_campaign=test
2. https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT

I've tried the following:

(?<=(utm_source=)).*(?=%3Futm)

but it doesn't give me RESULT for scenario 2.  Can someone please assist?

Comment: Getting HTTP 404 on both links

Answer (score 0):

The REGEX you are pasting means "identify the string between utm_source= and %3Futm". If "%3Futm" does not exist, it does not work. But if you state that "%3Futm" has to occur an arbitrary amount of times (including 0), it does work. So your solution is to add a star at the end of your regex:

```
(?<=(utm_source=)).*(?=%3Futm)*
```

Proof:

```
$ cat file
https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT%3Futm_campaign=test
https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT
$ grep -P "(?<=(utm_source=)).*(?=%3Futm)" file
https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT%3Futm_campaign=test
$ grep -P "(?<=(utm_source=)).*(?=%3Futm)*" file
https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT%3Futm_campaign=test
https://website.com/category/all-products?utm_source=RESULT
```

More to read: https://www.bingehacking.net/2021/10/regular-expressions-with-non-capturing.html

Comment: Thanks for your response and explanation Thorsten.  I've run the expression on regex101.com and yes it also matches the second RESULT but it also matches:  RESULT%3Futm_campaign=test instead of just matching RESULT in both.  Any suggestion on how I should change this?